# How to add group to ir.actions.server in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I 'm usin odoo 9. I have ir.actions.server on one of my model, I want this action to be invisible if user of specific group log in to the system? Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, both used models (`ir.actions.server` for the action itself and `ir.values` for the More-Menu entry) have no field for access groups. Hence there is no Odoo vanilla solution for your requirement.

But i looked into model `ir.values`. It has a field `user_id`. Maybe that could be used.